# In python, how would I create a new type from scratch which has a Meta class in it

Tags: python, metaprogramming

I would like to create a new type using `type(...)`. How do I provide the Meta class for this type?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't provide it to `type` as an argument, the metaclass would subclass `type` itself, so you would call the metaclass' constructor instead.

Comment: I am not sure I understand. Could you provide a code example for assigning a Meta with `abstract = True` or a link which explains this?

Comment: Are you talking about Django here?  Those aren't true metaclasses.  If what you want is a Django-style Meta class on a model, just create a class object with whatever class attributes you need, then add that class to the attributes dictionary you pass to `type` with the key `Meta`.